# Mac osx -- view contents of a symlink?

Tags: macos, mac, symbolic-link

Basically I want to look inside the symlink.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only thing inside a symlink is the target's name, so you want [`readlink(1)`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/readlink.1.html).

Comment: Or `ls -l` if your shell is configured the usual way.